# “Virus” Infection rate

Tags: probability

The latest worldwide virus has an infection rate of $0.1\%$ (that is, $1$ in $1000$ people actually have the virus). The chance that someone who has the virus tests positive is said to be $99\%$. The chance that someone who does not have the virus tests negative is also said to be $99\%$. What are the chances that someone who tests positive does not in fact have the virus (a “false positive”)?

My mathematics teacher, using Bayes’ theorem, showed that there are is a $91\%$ chance someone is a false positive. I feel like the problem has a flaw and incorrect assumption. Any thoughts?

Comment: You are about 100 times more likely to test positive if you have the virus than if you do not, but this is not commensurate with the prior improbability of having the virus (1000 to 1). The evidence isnt as extraordinary as the claim, to say it another way. Usually covid tests are applied when there are other reasons to believe you have the virus, like you have symptoms or you were in contact with an infected person, so the math changes a bit more in that case to what you would expect.

Comment: So how does the maths work out with those other considerations?

Comment: If you have other evidence for presence of the virus which is independent of the test itself, you can multiply the likelihood ratios together. The exact numbers depend on how we estimate the impact of other kinds of evidence. For instance, say we believe a person is 10 times more likely to have the virus than not if they recently encountered an infected person, and 10 times more likely to have the virus than not if they have symptoms.  If they also test positive then we can multiply the likelihood ratios together along with the prior 1000:1 odds to get 10:1 odds (91%) of having the virus.

Answer (score 2):

Consider an example of $100000$ men.
Among $100000$ men, $100$ men contracted the virus and $99$ will be tested positive.
There are $99900$ men without virus and among them $999$ will be tested positive (chance of being false positive is $1\%$) .
So among $999+99=1098$ men who are tested positive there are only $99$ men who actually have the virus.